# App Crash on Working with Facebook Connect

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

While I'm testing my app, is an UITableViewController navigation based app, sometimes, getting back or changing the view for another, I'm getting the next crash message. I can't solve this error, I don't know what is the responsible of this. Somebody can help me?

Thanks for reading.

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

When the app has finish, XCode points this Facebook Connect method.

```
- (void)dialogDidSucceed:(NSURL *)url {

  if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dialogCompleteWithUrl:)]) {
    [_delegate dialogCompleteWithUrl:url];
  }
  [self dismissWithSuccess:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the problem is solved. The best way to use the Facebook Connect SDK is to implement all the Facebook related objects into the App Delegate. When the user touch the button that allow to post into him Facebook wall (doesn't matter the UIView where the user is), you only have to call the App Delegate and get the Facebook objects that you need to call the Facebook Connect dialog. The App Delegate must be the Facebook Connect delegate for FBDialogDelegate and for FBSessionDelegate. Also, the App Delegate must implement the application: handleOpenURL: method.

Thanks to everyone for reading.